# Pressure Temperature relation of saturated steam

Tags: thermodynamics, steam

With the saturation pressure apparatus we did a heating and a colling process. We measured the temperature and afterwards we calculated the specifc volume of saturated vapour.

The question 1: What would the effect be if steam leaked out slowly during the experiment?

My proposal: If steam leaks out slowly during the experiment than a higher pressure is necessary to increase the temperature. Therefore the temperature wouldn’t increase with higher pressure.

Is it right?

The question 2: How do the values of the specifc volume of saturated vapour obtained using the experimental data compare with the tabulated values in the steam table?

I have no idea for question 2 :(

Comment: So, whose steam tables?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with whose steam table

Comment: You state "the steam table", so which one? Who produced it? Mine is an earlier edition of : https://www.slideshare.net/SGhallab/steam-tables-fifth-edition-by-rogers-and-mayhew

Comment: This one from your link is the steam table which I have to use

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

Saturation occurs at a fixed pressure and temperature.

a) In a constant volume experiment, assume that you keep enough liquid to assure the system is always at the two phase point (i.e. is always saturated). Assume the leak point has no affect on the internal pressure (i.e. this is the meaning of the term "slowly"). When vapor "leaks out (slowly)", more liquid will evaporate make up for the loss. The $p, T$ relationship at the two phase line is maintained.

b) In a constant volume experiment, assume that you do not have enough liquid to assure the system is always at the two phase point (i.e. is always saturated). When vapor "leaks out (slowly)", no liquid water is available to make up the loss. The system changes from saturation (two phase) to water vapor (single phase). The relationship between $p, T$ is no longer defined by the saturation line.

### Question 2

Steam tables contain values of $p, T$, and $\tilde{V}$ (specific volume). Compare your experimental value to that from a steam table at the given $p, T$.